# Probability question involving computer program

Tags: probability, proof-verification, bayes-theorem

Question:

A program consists of two modules. The first module contains an error with probability $0.2$. The second module is more complex, it has probability of $ \ 0.4$ to contain an error, independently of the first module. An error in the first module alone causes the program to crash with probability $ \ 0.5$. For the second module alone, this probability is $ \ 0.8$. If there are errors in both modules, the program crashes with probability $ \ 0.9$

1). What is the probability of a crash?

2). Suppose the program crashed. What is the probability of errors in both modules.

My attempt:

Let $ \ E_{1}:$ error in first module,
$ \ E_{2}:$ error in second module,
$ \ C :$ crash.

We know $ \ P(E_{1}) = 0.2, P(E_{2}) = 0.4, P(C|E_{1}) = 0.5, P(C|E_{2}) = 0.8, P(C|E_{1} \cap E_{2}) = 0.9$

$1). $$ \ P(C) = P(C \cap E_{1}) + P(C \cap E_{2}) = P(C|E_{1})P(E_{1}) + P(C|E_{2})P(E_{2}) = 0.42$

Therefore, probability of crash is $ \ 0.42$

$2)$ $P(E_{1} \cap E_{2} | C) = \frac{P[E_{1} \cap E_{2} \cap C]}{P(C)} = \frac{P[C|(E_{1} \cap E_{2})] P(E_{1} \cap E_{2})}{P(C)} = \frac{P[C|(E_{1} \cap E_{2})] P(E_{1}) P(E_{2})}{P(C)} $, since $ \ E_{1}$ and $ \ E_{2}$ are independant $ \ = \frac{(0.9)(0.2)(0.4)}{(0.42)} = 0.1714$

Is my approach and attempt correct? I am not too sure.

Comment: No, you've made a mistake. $Hint$: Is there an overlap in the occurrence of the two events?

Comment: Are you referring to part a ?

Comment: Yes. Do you think you have covered all possible cases?

Comment: $ \ P(C) = P(C \cap S) = P[C \cap (E_{1} \cup E_{2})] = P[(C \cap E_{1}) \cup (C \cap E_{2})] = P(C \cap E_{1}) + P(C \cap E_{2})$

Comment: Isn't this how you simplify?

Comment: There are three cases - $E_1$ alone, or $E_2$ alone, or both, occurring together

Comment: Could you please show me a formula? Im not quite sure.

Comment: $P(C) = P(C\cap (E_1 - E_2)) + P(C\cap (E_1\cap E_2)) + P(C\cap (E_2 - E_1))$

Comment: $ \ P(C) = P(C \cap E_{1}) + P(C \cap E_{2}) - P(C \cap E_{1} \cap E_{2})$. Would this be correct as well?

Comment: Yes, in fact that would be the better way to proceed

Comment: $ \ P(C) = P(C \cap E_{1}) + P(C \cap E_{2}) - P(C \cap E_{1} \cap E_{2}) =  P(C| E_{1})P(E_{1}) + P(C| E_{2})P(E_{2}) - P(C|E_{1} \cap E_{2})P(E_{1})P(E_{2}) = 0.2069 $.

Comment: How about this?

Comment: Are you sure about your calculation?